# Powershell Removing Quotes Argument

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, start-process

I'm using `Start-Process` to start another instance of Powershell as an administrator but when I try to pass the argument list, whether as a variable or as a plain string, Powershell removes the quotes. Below is the command I'm using:

```
$argu = '-noexit "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"';
powershell Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath powershell -ArgumentList $argu
```

This is the error I get:

```
x86 : The term 'x86' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:88
+ ... Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\v ...
+                    ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (x86:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Update:

```
$argu = '''-noexit ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat""''';
powershell Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath powershell -ArgumentList $argu
```

This almost fixes it but now I'm getting the error above in the **second** window instead of the first.

Comment: have you tried `$argu = '-noexit ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat""'`

Comment: `$argu = "-noexit", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"` Should also do it.

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns Updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(A) From *inside* PowerShell:**

```
$argu = '-noexit -command & \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat\"'
Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath powershell -ArgumentList $argu
```

<sup>Note: I'm not calling `Start-Process` via `powershell.exe`, as there is generally no need for that.</sup>

- The embedded `"` are `\`-escaped, which is what PowerShell requires when you call its *CLI* (perhaps surprisingly, given that PowerShell-internally it is `` ` `` that acts as the escape character).

  - That said given that the `"` are embedded inside `'...'` here, they shouldn't require *extra* escaping - see below.
- The file path to execute is prefixed with call operator `&`, because you need it in order to execute files that are specified in quoted form.
- Note that I've added `-Command`, which is not strictly necessary in Windows PowerShell, but would be if you ran your command from PowerShell *Core* (which now defaults to `-File`).

---

Alternatively, you could also specify your arguments individually, as part of an *array*, which is arguably the cleaner solution:

```
$argu = '-noexit', '-command', '&', 'de', 
  '\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat\"'
Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath powershell -ArgumentList $argu
```

Sadly, *even in this case you need the extra, embedded quoting* for arguments that contain spaces, which is [a known `Start-Process` problem being tracked on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576).

PowerShell's handling of quoting when calling external programs is generally problematic; the current issues are summarized in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/2361).

---

**(B) From *outside* PowerShell (`cmd.exe`, a custom File Explorer context menu):**

```
powershell -command Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath powershell -ArgumentList '-noexit -command . ''C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat'''
```

- *single*-quoting is now employed (with nested single quotes escaped as `''`), because double-quoting would substantially complicate the escaping.
- `.` is used instead of `&` to execute the `.bat` file, which avoids a problem with how the `&` is parsed; while `.` generally serves a different purpose than `&`, the two operators behave the same when calling *external* programs.
- If you also want to set the *working directory* for the PowerShell session that ultimately opens elevated, you need to incorporate an explicit `Set-Location` (`cd`) call into the command string, because `Start-Process -Verb RunAs` always defaults to the SYSTEM32 folder (even the `-WorkingDirectory` parameter doesn't help in that case).

  - For that to work safely, however, you must *quote* the directory path using *double*-quoting, given that file names may contain single quotes; with `%V` as the directory path (which File Explorer supplies to commands invoked via custom context menus), the properly escaped `Set-Location` call looks like this (I wish I were kidding):

    - `Set-Location \"\"\"%V%\"\"\"`

Integrated into the full command (using `Set-Location`'s built-in alias `cd` for brevity):

```
powershell -command Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath powershell -ArgumentList '-noexit -command cd \"\"\"%V%\"\"\"; . ''C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat'''
```

---

As an aside: PowerShell *Core* now has a `-WorkingDirectory` (`-wd`) CLI parameter that allows you to control the startup directory more robustly (`pwsh -wd "c:\path\to\dir" ...`); in fact, it was precisely the File Explorer custom context-menu use case that [prompted the introduction of this parameter](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6598).